# Java 8: List files from multiple paths

Tags: java, file, java-8

How to search files from multiple paths in Java 8. These are not sub/sibling directories. For example, if I want to search json files in a path, I have:

```
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(Paths.get(path), Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile() && p.toString().endsWith(".json"))) {
  stream.map((p) -> p.name).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Is there a better way to search in multiple paths? Or do I have to run the same code for multiple paths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do it. Assuming you have paths as a `List` of `String` objects, you can do it like so,

```
List<String> paths = ...;

paths.stream().map(path -> {
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(Paths.get(path))) {
        return stream.filter(p -> !p.toFile().isDirectory()).filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".json"))
                .map(Path::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log your ERROR here.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}).forEach(System.out::println);
```

In case if you need to get rid of the new-line character, then it can be done like this too.

```
paths.stream().map(path -> {
    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get(path))) {
        return stream.filter(p -> !p.toFile().isDirectory()).filter(p -> p.toString().endsWith(".json"))
                .map(Path::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}).flatMap(List::stream).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Here you get all the `.json` file names for each path into a `List`, and then flatten them into a flat `stream` of `String` objects before printing. Notice that the additional step involved in this approach which is `flatMap`.

Answer (score 4):

That’s what `flatMap` is for.

If you have a collection of `Path` instances in `path`, you may use

```
paths.stream()
     .flatMap(path -> {
         try { return Files.find(path, Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            (p, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile() && p.toString().endsWith(".json")); }
         catch (IOException ex) { throw new UncheckedIOException(ex); }
     })
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

It is a bit clumsy due to the fact that we have to deal with the checked `IOException` declared by `find` here. Rethrowing it as `UncheckedIOException` is the simplest choice as that’s what the stream returned by `find` will do anyway if an I/O problem occurs while processing the stream. Compare with [the documentation of `find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#find-java.nio.file.Path-int-java.util.function.BiPredicate-java.nio.file.FileVisitOption...-)

> If an [`IOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html) is thrown when accessing the directory after returned from this method, it is wrapped in an [`UncheckedIOException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) which will be thrown from the method that caused the access to take place.

So doing the same within our function simplifies the caller’s error handling, as it just has to handle `UncheckedIOException`s.

There is no way to use `try(…)` here, but that’s exactly the reason why `flatMap` will remove this burden from us. As [its documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) states:

> Each mapped stream is [closed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#close--) after its contents have been placed into this stream.

So, once our function has returned the sub-stream, the Stream mplementation will do the right thing for us.

You may chain arbitrary stream operations in place of `.forEach(System.out::println);` to process all elements of the flattened stream like a single stream.

If your input collection contains instances of `String` instead of `Path`, you may simply prepend `paths.stream().map(Paths::get)` instead of `paths.stream()` to the `flatMap` operation.