# How to group files based on filenames from multiple paths in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-11

I would like to group specific files based on their file names from multiple paths.  I have followed this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50788852/java-8-list-files-from-multiple-paths).  I have not been able to loop through each file after I start streaming the path to find that specific file name.

Here are the paths with files contents:

```
/var/tmp/data_sample1/data2_first_example.set.csv
/var/tmp/data_sample1/data3_first_example.set.csv
/var/tmp/data_sample1/data1_first_example.set.csv
/var/tmp/data_sample2/data2_second_example.set.csv
/var/tmp/data_sample2/data1_second_example.set.csv
/var/tmp/data_sample2/data3_second_example.set.csv
/tmp/csv_files/data_sample3/data2_third_example.set.csv
/tmp/csv_files/data_sample3/data1_third_example.set.csv
/tmp/csv_files/data_sample3/data3_third_example.set.csv
```

Enum Class:

```
enum PersonType {
    A,
    B
}
```

FileName.java

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class FileName {
    private final String first = "_first_sample";
    private final String second = "_second_sample";
    private final String third = "_third_sample";

    private final List<String> filenames = Arrays.asList(first, second, third);
    public List<String> getFilenames() {
        return filenames;
    }
}
```

CSVFiles.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CSVFiles {

    private PersonType personType;
    private List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<File> firstSample = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<File> secondSample = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<File> thirdSample = new ArrayList<>();

    public CSVFiles(PersonType personType, List<String> paths) {
        if (personType == PersonType.A) {
            this.personType = personType;
            FileName fileName = new FileName();
            this.fileNames = fileName.getFilenames();
            setCSVFiles(paths);
        }
    }

    public List<File> setCSVFiles(List<String> paths) {
        List<Path> collect = paths.stream()
                .flatMap(path -> {
                    try {
                        return Files.find(Paths.get(path), Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                (p, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile()
                                        && p.toString().contains(".set")
                                        && p.toString().endsWith(".csv")
                        );
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return collect.stream()
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .filter(file -> {
                    if (file.getName().contains("_first_sample")) {
                        firstSample.add(file);
                        return true;
                    } else if (file.getName().contains("_second_sample")) {
                        secondSample.add(file);
                        return true;
                    } else if (file.getName().contains("_third_sample")) {
                        thirdSample.add(file);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

CSVFilesTest.java

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class CSVFilesTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        String data_sample1 = "/var/tmp/data_sample1";
        String data_sample2 = "/var/tmp/data_sample2";
        String data_sample3 = "/tmp/csv_files/data_sample3";
        List<String> paths = Arrays.asList(data_sample1, data_sample2, data_sample3);
        System.out.println(paths);

        CSVFiles csvFiles = new CSVFiles(PersonType.A, paths);
    }
}
```

Desired Output:

```
firstSample: [data1_first_example.set.csv, data2_first_example.set.csv, data3_first_example.set.csv] 
secondSample: [data1_second_example.set.csv, data2_second_example.set.csv, data3_second_example.set.csv]
thirdSample:  [data1_third_example.set.csv, data2_third_example.set.csv, data3_third_example.set.csv]
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: In your collect method you are looking for [groupingby](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) you could remove the data prefix and the extension from the end of the path and use that as the grouping criteria

Comment: Thank you @Sync it, will groupingby specify for each file in a specific file list? Maybe some code snip will help.

Comment: If you are grouping by file name only then put all of your file paths in one large list of strings(or a list of paths and then use map to convert them into strings) and you could do something like collect(Collectors.groupingBy(path->path.subString(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1))); .This will return you Map<String,List<String>> where the key is the file name(which you extracted in the grouping by clause), and the value is the list of all paths ending with(or having) the file name.

Comment: Thank you so much @Sync it! That worked better!  I added an update with your solution.  Now I want to close this story as solved....

Comment: Glad I could help but please put your solution as an actual answer(don't edit the question with your solution)and mark it as accepted so not only would it help others having your problem but you would also gain reputation points when people upvote your answer

Comment: Done miss that post answer button, ok it will let me check as answered after 12 hours so will that later. Thank you @Syncit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution thanks to "sync it" comments:

```
    public Map<String, List<String>> setCSVFiles(List<String> paths) {
        List<Path> collect = paths.stream()
                .flatMap(path -> {
                    try {
                        return Files.find(Paths.get(path), Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                                (p, attrs) -> attrs.isRegularFile()
                                        && p.toString().contains(".set")
                                        && p.toString().endsWith(".csv")
                        );
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        throw new UncheckedIOException(ex);
                    }
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return collect.stream()
                .map(Path::toString)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(path ->
                        path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
                        ));
    }
```